# JavaFX: Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.sun.prism.GraphicsPipeline.is3DSupported()"

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, javafx-8

I am programming a JavaFX Application which shows an undecorated stage. To close my application, I use a button, which calls the method `System.exit(0);`
The problem is that I get sometimes this exception without links to my code when I use it:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.sun.prism.GraphicsPipeline.is3DSupported()" because the return value of "com.sun.prism.GraphicsPipeline.getPipeline()" is null
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.isSupported(QuantumToolkit.java:1208)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.isSupportedImpl(PlatformImpl.java:960)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.isSupported(PlatformImpl.java:627)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.application.Platform.isSupported(Platform.java:252)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.input.PickResultChooser.processOffer(PickResultChooser.java:182)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.input.PickResultChooser.offer(PickResultChooser.java:143)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.intersects(Node.java:5226)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node$1.intersects(Node.java:544)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.intersects(NodeHelper.java:258)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.doPickNodeLocal(Region.java:3161)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region$1.doPickNodeLocal(Region.java:184)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.RegionHelper.pickNodeLocalImpl(RegionHelper.java:104)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.pickNodeLocal(NodeHelper.java:128)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.pickNode(Node.java:5199)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.pickChildrenNode(Parent.java:806)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.pickChildrenNode(Parent.java:136)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.pickChildrenNode(ParentHelper.java:113)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.doPickNodeLocal(Region.java:3160)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region$1.doPickNodeLocal(Region.java:184)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.RegionHelper.pickNodeLocalImpl(RegionHelper.java:104)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.pickNodeLocal(NodeHelper.java:128)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.pickNode(Node.java:5199)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.pickChildrenNode(Parent.java:806)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.pickChildrenNode(Parent.java:136)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.pickChildrenNode(ParentHelper.java:113)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.doPickNodeLocal(Region.java:3160)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region$1.doPickNodeLocal(Region.java:184)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.RegionHelper.pickNodeLocalImpl(RegionHelper.java:104)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.pickNodeLocal(NodeHelper.java:128)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.pickNode(Node.java:5199)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.pickNode(Scene.java:3999)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.pick(Scene.java:2031)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3809)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1851)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2584)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:409)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:299)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:447)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:412)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:446)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

Comment: Try using `Platform.exit()` instead of `System.exit(0);`. That will cleanly shut down the JavaFX subsystem; if there are no non-daemon threads running it will subsequently cause the JVM to exit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

call Platform.exit() instead of System.exit();

Answer (score 0):

There is another option to use following, if we still need to call

> System.exit()

.

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                });
```